# BeginInvoke method and Session State

Tags: ajax, session, asynchronous

I am invoking a asynchronous `PageMethod` call from the client-side. The backend code is

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string BeginMethodCall()
        { //Session Accessible here
            string g = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();                    
            Func<object> f = () => MethodCall();                

            IAsyncResult asyncCall = f.BeginInvoke(null, f);

            lock (AsyncThreadPool)
                AsyncThreadPool[g] = asyncCall;
            return g;
        }            

        [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
        public static object EndMethodCall(string guId)
        {
            IAsyncResult callResult;
            lock (AsyncThreadPool)
            {
                callResult = AsyncThreadPool[guId];
                AsyncThreadPool.Remove(guId);
            }

            Func<object> f = (Func<object>)callResult.AsyncState;
            callResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            return f.EndInvoke(callResult);
        }

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static object MethodCall()
        {
            //Session not accessible here
        }
```

Session state is accessible from `BeginMethodCall()` and `EndMethodCall()` but not from the `MethodCall()`.

Can anyone tell me why I lose my session state here?

1. Do threads lose the Session context because asyn calls are not thread safe?
2. Is there a way to access session here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone may find this useful

BeginXXX does create a new theard and threads are not session safe for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0):

In general,

Session + Async = fail

You're safe within callbacks and before you branch off into async code, but while you're in parallel, you don't get full session state.

However, there are a few workarounds. The easiest of which is

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

at the controller level, which allows, obviously, read-only access to session values. It'll work in parallel as long as you don't try to *write* to session. You can also implement your own HttpHandler, but that ones a little tougher.